# Dynamic HTML Table with in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

Requirement is build a appointment chart dynamically based on the data.

For example I am getting the below data from apex controller.

```
apWrap[{"appChartMap":{"Treatment Patients":true,"Delivery":true,"Office Visit (Existing GP non-exam;)":true,"Limited Exam (Pt with an issue)":true,"Online Teledentistry Visit":true},"apmntName":"Teledentistry \"spots\""}
```

So table should be something like below.

[image]

This what I have tried but not successful yet. What am I missing here?

```
<template if:true={apmntSlots}> 
  <lightning-card title="Appointment Info" icon-name="custom:custom19" class="slds-card_boundary">
    <div class="slds-var-m-around_medium">
      <thead>
        <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
          <template for:each={apmntSlots} for:item="header">
            <th key={header}>
              <div class="slds-truncate">{header.key}</div>
            </th>
          </template>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </div>
</lightning-card>
```

```
    export default class pds_GuidedActions_Comp extends LightningElement {

@track LogcallID;
@track AppoinmentName=[];
@track _ApprovedSlots=[]; 

@api
get apmntSlots(){       
   return this.getAppmntSlots();
}

set apmntSlots(value){
    this._ApprovedSlots = value;
}


getAppmntSlots(){        
    fetchChartValues({
        logId: this.LogcallID
    })
        .then((data) => {
            this.error = null; 
            this.AppoinmentName = data[0].apmntName;            
            for (let key in data[0].appChartMap) {                    
                this._ApprovedSlots.push({value:"True", key:key});
             }
            console.log('chart_name',this.AppoinmentName);                
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('error',error);
        });
}

}
```

Comment: Note that using [lightning-datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example) will help you if you are happy with SLDS styling.

Comment: When you say that you have not been successful yet, what do your current attempt look like and what is the gap between that and what you're hoping to achieve? Agree with @KeithC that if you're happy with the SDLC styling then using the lightning-datatable is your best option.